# javascript add ondrastart to img

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have this code that is supposed to create 10 draggable img elements

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var trash = GenerateTrash(i);
                container.appendChild(trash); 
            }
            function GenerateTrash(i) {
                var trash = document.createElement("img");
                trash.src = "crumpled-paper.png";
                trash.id = i;
                trash.draggable = true;
                trash.ondragstart = function () { ev.dataTransfer.setData("dragged-id", ev.target.id); };
                return trash;
            }
```

However, when I run it through the debugger, the "ondragstart" function simply isn't there. Help ?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you forgot to include `ev` parameter into your anonymous function?

Comment: tried that way too, same thing..

 edit: actually just tried it again, it works now..
but it still don't see ondragstart in the debugger..